# With a custom built PC that hasn't gone through the BIOS setup could I get Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, bios, usb-installation

So I just built a PC with 8 cores (4.0Ghz) and a GTX750. So since I don't have a OS on it yet could I download Ubuntu on a USB and install it as my OS on the BIOS setup? I don't know much about how to install a OS so...
Any replies will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, just boot Ubuntu and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an great rig!

Assuming you properly set up you USB drive to be bootable image of Ubuntu and enable your BIOS to boot from USB (if required) then Yes.

If you are new to installing OS's I would suggest to download the Ubuntu ISO and burn it to CD/DVD then install it that way.